# Does reducing the number of signal assignments reduce the simulation time of VHDL code ?

Tags: vhdl, simulation

I have now read twice that by reducing the number of signal assignments one can improve the simulation performance for VHDL code. In [vhdl2proc](http://www.gaisler.com/doc/vhdl2proc.pdf) Gaisler states that signal assignment takes about 100 times longer than variable assignment. And in the Book "VHDL Answers to Frequently Asked Questions" by Ben Cohen (pp. 222) it is also said that combining multiple signal assignments into one improves simulation time, but he doesn't name any numbers.

By reducing I don't mean simply omitting them but e.g. put multiple signals into a record, work with a variable of that record and then assign the variable type record to the signal type record at the end of a process, thus greatly reducing the number of signal assignments.

I think the claim sounds reasonable, not sure about 100x improvement though, but since I want to include this into my thesis it would be nice to have a source for it. Could maybe someone confirm this claim, or even better give a source to back it up ?

Comment: depends on the simulator for starters.  It should be somewhat obvious that the job of simulation is not linear, a design that is twice the size should take more than twice the time to sim, perhaps four times (squared instead of doubled).  Simulators keep improving and again one would assume that at compile time whole chunks of signals can be determined to be synchronous (vs combinational) and the software does not need to touch or evaluate those until a clock cycle.  And numerous other tricks.

Comment: designs that have say a counter for debugging purposes might cause a whole module to be evaluated for just that one thing within that module costing a lot of sim time.  Designs that say keep bus signals zero except for the cycles where the bus is valid, basically making two state changes on some of the bus instead of one, adds both power in silicon and sim time in simulation.

Comment: so you could add a large number of signals in the right place and not change the sim time much.  you could remove a lot of signals in the right place and not improve the sim time much.  Likewise you could add a small number of signals in the right place and make it dramatically wors and remove a small number and make it dramatically faster.   "it depends" on where the signals are and your simulator and other tools

Comment: what helps one simulator is not necessarily expected to work on another.

Comment: saying all that, the fewer signals the less work overall the simulator has to do, whether or not it changes performance is a different question, but less does help.

Comment: While all that is true, I am interested in whether the claim that reducing the number of signal assignments by replacing those assignments with variables is true, for all simulators and projects in general. Yes, vendors can take different routes in optimizing the code for simulation, but in the end they still have to follow the language reference (more or less :) ). And since the scope of a variable is always limited to within a process, it doesn't seem too far fetched to reason that in general variable assignment is a more light weight undertaking.

Comment: Have you considered benchmarking? You can imagine the results are very much design specification dependent. Apply some science here to support applying someone else's assertion.

Comment: @user1155120 I have, but I can't think of a simple way to prove it. I could generate a dummy testbench with many signals and update them in some fashion, then time another benchmark for the same testbench but now with signals inside a variable record. But all that will (maybe) tell me is that this specific example supports the claim.

Comment: I can't really change the code base of the project to have a comparison, since the project is massive. I was hoping since two authors at least mentioned it, it is something that can be proven on a more conceptual level. But if in the end there is no such prove, I probably will try a simple benchmark, shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: There isnt an answer since it is based on implementation, you have to go benchmark specific code on a specific simulator to even begin to understand the claim.  That or discard the paper you read if it is making claims that make no sense.  Now if the paper is talking about a specific simulator version on a specific computer with specific code, okay that is fair.